# How to click to clone all id's that match these classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a page where I click a button and add content to a div. Right now I have three buttons that all have at least one class. Each class corresponds to a single div id that has its own content. What I'm trying to do is grab each class that is on the button, find the div id that has the same name, clone it, and append it to the #return div.

I have a working example that will only clone the first class name it sees on the button. How can I have my jquery find all div id's that match the classes on the button, clone them, and append them to #return?

These buttons can have the same class but when it's cloned in the #return, I don't want it cloned again. I have an if statement that tries to prevent this but it ends up deleting them. How can I stop this?

I have [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zyech6L3/1/) here that shows this jquery working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[id^=button]").click(function() {
    var myclass = $(this).attr("class").split(" ");

    if ($(this).is(".a1,.a2,.a3")) {
      $("div#" + myclass).first().clone().appendTo("#return");
    }

    if ($("#return div#" + myclass).length > 1) {
      $("#return div#" + myclass + ":last").remove();
      }

  });
});
```

Comment: One thing that the answers have not mentioned, is that when you clone an element, it has the same ID as its clone. IDs must be unique in the document, so something like `div#a1:last` is the same as `div#a1`, since there can only be one `div` with the ID `a1`. Note that `div#a1` is also redundant, since `#a1` would uniquely identify the one element with the ID `a1`, whether that element is a `div` or not.

Comment: Is this going to cause any problems while using? If I were to remove div#a1 it would remove all of them that are currently on the page but if I target the div#return and remove them it should only remove div#a1 when it's already been cloned and appendTo #return.

Comment: IDs must be unique in the document. In other words, if you have more than one `div#a1` in your document, it is an invalid document, and you'll have a number of other problems in the future.

Comment: So then I should change the id before cloning. Maybe change it to #clone + myclass. Here is a new answer based on @Gaby aka G. Petrioli answer. https://jsfiddle.net/zyech6L3/3/

Comment: Well, in that fiddle you're actually changing the id after cloning, but that's what you want anyway :).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan That's what I meant to say. Change ID after cloning. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `myclass` is an array, so when you add that as a string to create a selector like `"div#" + myclass` it ends up creating a selector `"div#a1,a2"` which is not what you want.

You should iterate over the `myclass` array and perform your logic for each class.

Something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("[id^=button]").click(function() {
        var myclass = $(this).attr("class").split(" ");

        if ($(this).is(".a1,.a2,.a3")) {
            myclass.forEach(function(currentClass) {
                if ($("#return div#" + currentClass).length == 0)
                    $("div#" + currentClass).first().clone().appendTo("#return");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Updated demo at: https://jsfiddle.net/zyech6L3/2/

Comment: Ah, that makes so much sense! Yes this is working exactly as I need it to be. And the if statement works great not allowing it to duplicate again. Thank you so much!

Comment: I had a suggestion from @MikeMcCaughan about cloning a div and not changing the ID. Using your answer I added a bit to clone the div and change the id to #klone + myclass. https://jsfiddle.net/zyech6L3/3/

Comment: @cgrouge indeed that is required to have valid html and avoid some pitfalls in the future. Good fix.

Answer (score 1):

you need to iterate through to check what classes are available. 
like:

```
for(var j=0; j<myclass.length; j++){
  $("div#" + myclass[j]).first().clone().appendTo("#return");
}
```

see this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/c4soamkr/

Comment: This was almost exactly what I needed. I didn't realize mine wasn't iterating through each class of the button. This makes sense now! This solution didn't stop cloning after it was already cloned